# Pandoc: Convert Word to LaTeX, with all images as .png Files?

Tags: latex, imagemagick, pandoc

How do I convert a Word document to a LaTeX document, while all images in the final LaTeX document should be .png files with a DPI of 300?

Answer (score 0):

The conversion from Word to Latex can be achieved be using [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/). All images can be extracted using the following command:

```
pandoc --extract-media ./myMediaFolder doc.docx -o doc.tex
```

The conversion of all images to `.png` files can be achieved using [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php). The following script converts all images from the `image` folder to `.png` files. Just name the script something like `convertImages.ps1` and place it in the same folder, where the `image` folder is. On Windows, right click and run with PowerShell.

```
$InputFolderPath = 'images'
$OutputFolderPath = 'converted_images'

if(!(Test-Path $OutputFolderPath)){
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $OutputFolderPath
}

Get-ChildItem -Path $InputFolderPath -Recurse -File |
ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Extension -ne ".png") {
        $pngFilename = Join-Path $OutputFolderPath ($_.BaseName + ".png")
        magick convert -density 300 $_.FullName $pngFilename
        Write-Output "Converted image $($_.FullName) to png format"
    }
}

Write-Output "Image conversion completed."
```

If you are using Mac or Linux, the bash command looks like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

InputFolderPath='images'
OutputFolderPath='converted_images'

# if output folder doesn't exist, create it
mkdir -p $OutputFolderPath

# loop through all files in the input directory
for file in $InputFolderPath/*; do
    # only operate on files
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        # file extension
        extension="${file##*.}"

        # if file is not PNG
        if [ "$extension" != "png" ] && [ "$extension" != "PNG" ]; then
            # Output file name
            base=$(basename -- "$file")
            base_name="${base%.*}"
            png_filename="$OutputFolderPath/$base_name.png"

            # Convert the image to PNG (indicator -density 300)
            convert -density 300 "$file" "$png_filename"

            # Log message
            echo "Converted image $file to png format"
        fi
    fi
done

# conversion complete
echo "Image conversion completed."
```